# Is it possible to config a signalR method to only called from server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a client application(C# desktop application) that connected to server side application(asp.net mvc application) with signalR, now i want  when a costumer buy one of my products from site, the sale reported to client application.
But for security reasons i think it is good way to limit call "my signalR reporter method" only from server side! But i don't know how can i do it?

Comment: Where else are you expecting it to be called from? It's not like a server connection where it's listening all the time for incoming connections. The client has to initiate the connection with the server.

Comment: you'll need to show some code on how you're calling your hub without it being from a client connection.

Comment: @DLeh i think it is not important how i call signalR methods from client application. When a product sold with my site, I need say signalR a product sold and signalR must says to client administration application that product is sold(real time reporting). If the reporting method called from site that means any body can see it.

Comment: I wanted to achieve this in a different scenario, where a frontend developer used server methods which he clearly shouldn't have used.

Answer (score -1):

What you wanna do is signal the users that a product has been updated

First get the context,

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProductHub>()
```

Then you can update the clients in different ways, all clients

```
context.Clients.All.updateProduct(product);
```

Specific client (Connection Id)

```
context.Clients.Client(id).updateProduct(product)
```

User id

```
context.Clients.User(userId).updateProduct(product)
```

Make sure to abstract the Hub context from your domain logic, its bad practice to have high coupling between them.

You can also use a library that abstracts it for you, I have created such library and I think it will suit your need perfect, you use any type of event aggregator or message bus, after that you call your bus fro your domain method like

```
eventAggregator.Publish(new ProductUpdated(product));
```

My library will kick in and deliver the update to the clients. Look here

http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/

Comment: Question was if it is possible to restrict that methods can be called only from server. This does not answer that.

Comment: Hub methods are designed to be called through signalr clients. There is no point in having a hub method that cant be called from a client. But you do not need to be in the context of a hub method, just call, GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProductHub>(). So my answer does answer the question.

Comment: Dear @Anders, I think you mean that i use signalR context like a static object and call methods with context. 
I don't like to use signalR methods to any functionality of my web app. I think it is very well to call signalR report methods in delegets(event methods).

Comment: You mean the built in IProgress interface?